# Object not being updated when copied/assigned from Cloned Object in C#

Tags: c#

I have the following code also at [dot net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5YCMvk)

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        ObjectA objectA = new ObjectA();

        objectA.Id = 99;
        objectA.Name = "Joe King";

        Console.WriteLine("BEFORE");
        Console.WriteLine(objectA.Id.ToString() + "|" + objectA.Name);

        ObjectB objectB = new ObjectB(objectA);

        objectB.DoSomething();
        Console.WriteLine("AFTER");
        Console.WriteLine(objectA.Id.ToString() + "|" + objectA.Name);

    }
}


public class ObjectB
{
    ObjectA _objA = null;
    ObjectA _objACopy = null;

    public ObjectB(ObjectA objA)
    {
        _objA = objA;
        _objACopy = Object.Clone<ObjectA>(objA);
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        _objA.Id = 100;
        _objA.Name = "Bob Smith";
    }
}


public class ObjectA
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

public class Object
{
    public static T Clone<T>(T source)
    {
        var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(source);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(serialized);
    }
}
```

Which gives my the following result, which is correct.

BEFORE

99|Joe King

AFTER

100|Bob Smith

However, if I wanted to undo the change on the original object, I changed my method DoSomething() to this (this is the [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bRCVWS))

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    _objA.Id = 100;
    _objA.Name = "Bob Smith";

    _objA = _objACopy;
}
```

But the result is wrong;

BEFORE

99|Joe King

AFTER

100|Bob Smith

The correct result should be as below;

BEFORE

99|Joe King

AFTER

99|Joe King

So by assigning Object to Object doesn't work, but if I assign each individual property like this, it does work (this is the [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SspCCs))

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    _objA.Id = 100;
    _objA.Name = "Bob Smith";

    _objA.Id = _objACopy.Id;
    _objA.Name = _objACopy.Name;
}
```

Can somebody please help me understand what is going wrong and why I can call

> _objA = _objACopy;

To get back to the original object.

Comment: I'm really confused. Why are you making a copy to modify the original?

Comment: This example is taken from a bigger project.  Basically the object is passed into a Winform (form).  If the user makes changes, and wants to undo them I can revert them.  This is why I'm showing like this, to help explain the issue I'm experiencing

Comment: @Tommo1977  I don't think is a good approach for undo functionality.  Have you considered immutable objects and stacks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is, that object variables in C# are **reference types**.

Reference types variables are variables, that only hold a reference to where the object is stored inside your memory. If you now assign an object to another object it will only assign that memory address to your variable.

So you now have 2 variables `objA` and `objACopy` that both point to the same object in your memory. If you now change the property `Id` of you `objA` it will therefor also change in `objACopy`.

```
objACopy = objA;
objACopy.Id = 1111;
// objA.Id is now also changed to 1111, beacuse they point to the same memory address
```

If you want to change `objA`, without affecting `objACopy` you have to copy the whole object instead of only the memory adress. To do this you can just create a new object using the `new` keyword and copy its properties over from the other object. That way you end up with 2 different object that each have their own memory space and don't affect each other.

Comment: Perhaps think about using something like Automapper

Comment: I thought by calling Object.Clone<ObjectA>(objA); I was making a new object

Comment: @Tommo1977 that is correct, but by doing `_objA = _objACopy;` you overwrite the variable `_objA` again and assign to it a reference to `_objACopy`. By this all the changes you made to the id and name of `_objA` have no effect anymore. You change the pointer of variable `_objA` from its own object to the one of `_objACopy`, resulting in both using the same memory object. So in the end `_objA` has now the same properties as `_objACopy`.

Comment: @Tommo1977 I think I understand now what you meant sorry :S
The problem is you are using the wrong clone method. Try to use Object.MemberwiseClone instead http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.object.memberwiseclone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Because `_objA = _objACopy` doesn't change the object originally assigned to `_obja`, it just changes the object that `_objA` is referencing.

This is the smallest example to reproduce your issue:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var foo  = new Foo { Bar = "bar" };
        Console.WriteLine("Before: {0}", foo.Bar);
        ChangeBar(foo);
        Console.WriteLine("After: {0}", foo.Bar);
        ChangeBarReference(foo);
        Console.WriteLine("After reference: {0}", foo.Bar);     
    }

    private static void ChangeBar(Foo foo)
    {
        foo.Bar = "baz";
    }

    private static void ChangeBarReference(Foo foo)
    {
        foo = new Foo { Bar = "qux" };
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
Before: bar
After: baz
After reference: baz
```

And not "qux" at the last line, because you can only do that if you make the signature `ref Foo foo`.

```
private static void ChangeBarReferenceRef(ref Foo foo)
{
    foo = new Foo { Bar = "tok" };
}   

// ...

ChangeBarReferenceRef(ref foo);
Console.WriteLine("After ref reference: {0}", foo.Bar);
```

Prints:

```
Before: bar
After: baz
After reference: baz
After ref reference: tok
```